# Import from nested components ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import

Okay so i really thought this would be simple or at least able to find similar problem by searching google but haven't found anything that help.

So i got two files one in the path

```
/src/components/menu/header/InformationHeader
```

and one in

```
/src/components/menu/sections/section_components/PromotionComponent
```

what i want to do is import InformationHeader into PromotionComponent but i cant seem to find a way how i tried

```
import { InformationHeader } from "../menu/header/InformationHeader";
import { InformationHeader } from "../header/InformationHeader";
```

and with all different combination of dots but nothing find it. I dont want to use an absolute path for it either with my username and all. I know there must be a simple solution for this but just cant find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you need to go up 2 folders..

```
import { InformationHeader } from "../../header/InformationHeader";
```

You are now in..

```
/src/components/menu/sections/section_components/PromotionComponent
```

so, now `../../` means you are now

```
/src/components/menu/
```

Comment: I knew there were the simplest solution to this :) thanks been pulling my hair for a while here

Comment: Done it couldnt do it at first because time and then i forgot!